# Weird mouse behaviour in Debian Wheezy (jumpy cursor)

Tags: debian, mouse, xorg, debian-wheezy

When I move my mouse slowly over the desktop the pointer jumps often a few pixels (one or two) in the opposite direction of which I move my mouse. Horribly when trying to set the cursor around some semicolons in eclipse. I guess this is the result of a wrong set resolution. I suppose this is because the mouse was set initially really fast and even if I do `xset m 1/2 3`, the mouse is just to fast and unprecise for me.

It aready tried to configure the xorg.conf like this:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Configured Mouse"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Device"    "/dev/mouse"
    Option      "Protocol"  "Auto"
    Option      "Name" "Logitech G3"
    Option      "Resolution" "2000"
EndSection
```

But with no effect.

**EDIT**
But one new thing I recognized is that, in the mouse settings, I can slide the slider to max or to min. Mouse behaviour (sensitivity) does not change. I found somthing curoious too in /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[   257.409] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Gaming Mouse (/dev/input/event1)
[   257.409] (**) Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[   257.409] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB Gaming Mouse'
[   257.409] (**) Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: always reports core events
[   257.409] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[   257.409] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc042
[   257.409] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: Found 20 mouse buttons
[   257.409] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[   257.409] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: Found relative axes
[   257.409] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[   257.409] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[   257.409] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[   257.409] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[   257.409] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[   257.409] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input1/event1"
[   257.409] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Gaming Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 8)
[   257.409] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[   257.409] (**) Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   257.409] (**) Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[   257.409] (**) Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   257.409] (**) Logitech USB Gaming Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   257.409] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Gaming Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[   257.409] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   257.409] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

Still my question is:

**How do I setup my mouse correctly in Debian wheezy?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay well that took a while. But I got a solution. Meanhile I even bought a new mouse.

When you have a mouse with a high dpi you can use its standard dpi with minimum acceleration (which is anyway going to be to fast) follow these steps:

1. Get `xinput`

   `$ sudo apt-get install xinput`
2. List your input devices

   `xinput --list`

   You should get an output like this:

   ```
   ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer            id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ HID 1d57:0005                         id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
       ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard           id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Power Button                          id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Power Button                          id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ```
3. I my case my "HAMA uRAGE" is HID 1d57:0005. Remember its id.
4. Now comes the magic. I would prefer to be able to increase the resolution but debian obv dont want me to. Type in:

   ```
   xinput set-float-prop <id> 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' <d>;
   ```

where  is to be replaced by your mouse's id and  the deceleration factor. Your have to play around a little bit. Like me. At least X doeas not need a restart for applynig the changes. Greets

**EDIT:**

To make it permanent edit X11 settings.

`sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Add: Option "ConstantDeceleration" "10"

Example:

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier "My mouse"
   MatchIsPointer "true"
   Option "ConstantDeceleration" "10"
EndSection
```